# For a closed proper convex function $f(x)$, how to show ${\inf _{x \in {\mathbb{R}^n}}}\{ f(x) - {x^T}y\} $ is the intercept of the tangent plane?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

For a closed differentiable proper convex function $f(x):\Bbb R^n \to (-\infty, +\infty] $, given a fixed $y \in \Bbb R^n$, how to show that

> if ${\inf _{x \in {\mathbb{R}^n}}}\{ f(x) - {x^T}y\} \neq -\infty $ and the infimum attains, then it is the intercept of the tangent plane through $x$ at the $z$-axis, and the gradient of $f$ at $x$ is $y$

as illustrated in the following chart? A function is closed if its epigraph is closed. Thanks!

> [image]

Comment: Thanks I added the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is wrong,  Let's call $F(y)= \inf_{x \in {\mathbb{R}^n}}\{ f(x) - {x^T}y\}$ , take $f(x) = e^{-x}$, for this function $F(0)=0$ but the derivative of $f$ is always nonzero!
If $\inf$ is attained then your claim is correct, I think.
Now Let suppose infimum is attained then, there exist $x_0 \in R^n$ such that $F(y)=f(x_0) - {x_0^T}y$ Hence  for all $x \in R^n$  $$ f(x_0) - {x_0^T}y \leq f(x) - {x^T}y $$ $$  {(x- x_0)^T}y \leq f(x)-f(x_0)$$

This shows $y \in \partial f(x_0) = \{\nabla f (x_0)\}. $ So $y= \nabla f(x_0).$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also add this condition.

Comment: Hi, could you help explain a little more about why ${(x- x_0)^T}y \leq f(x)-f(x_0)$ implies $y \in \partial f(x_0) = \{\nabla f (x_0)\}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that the function $\varphi(x) := f(x) - x\cdot y$ attains a minimum at some point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

At this point $\nabla \varphi(x_0) = 0$, is $\nabla f(x_0) - y = 0$.
The equation of the tangent plane of $f$ at $(x_0, f(x_0))$ is then
$$
z = f(x_0) + y\cdot (x-x_0).
$$
At $x=0$ you get $z = f(x_0) - x_0\cdot y = \varphi(x_0)$.

Comment: This proof has a drawback I think!  You cannot conclude $\nabla \phi(x_0) = 0$ Since you are minimizing $\phi$ over the **consrtraint** dom(f)$=\{x\in R^n ~| \quad  f(x) < \infty \}$ !

Comment: If you assume that $f$ is differentiable at each point of $\text{dom}(f)$, then $\text{dom}(f)$ must be open.